# What would Math.scalb be used for?

Tags: java, math

Just perusing the docs and found this odd function, Math.scalb().  Just wondering if anyone has had experience using this function.  What kind of things would you use Math.scalb for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `java.lang.Math.scalb(float f,int scaleFactor)`, rather than something like the following (one shift, one conversion and a double multiplication) :

```
double a = Integer.doubleValue(1 << scaleFactor);
f *= a;
```

or

```
double a = Math.pow(2, scaleFactor);
f *= a;
```

It uses the fact that a double is already written in the form [image: floating point format], see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point. Thus simply one addition :

```
exponent += scaleFactor;
```

with correct treatment of corner cases obviously, as the documentation details. So its used to do an efficient `f * 2 ^ scaleFactor`

---

Some reference : according to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-math2/#scalb

> When testing with Apple's Java 6 VM, for example, Math.scalb() was reproducibly two orders of magnitude faster than x*Math.pow(2, y)

Comment: `Math.getExponent()` is also related.

Answer (score 2):

It's used for exponential retry mechanisms.

Below is one of the usages from within Android framework:

```
// Retry after exponential backoff timeout
final long timeoutMs = (long) Math.scalb(BACKOFF_MILLIS, mConnectionBackoffAttempts);
mHandler.postDelayed(mConnectionRunnable, timeoutMs);
mConnectionBackoffAttempts++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.Math.scalb(float f,int scaleFactor) returns f x 2scaleFactor rounded as if performed by a single correctly rounded floating-point multiply to a member of the double value set. For details refer this, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_scalb_float.htm

Comment: I read the docs, thanks.  I'm asking what it would be used for.